# Spring cloud dataflow nexus

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to create a task with spring cloud dataflow fetching the jar from nexus repository. I am able to get the jar from local maven repository but not from remote nexus repository

Answer (score 0):

The Maven [configuration-section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-maven-configuration) in the reference guide goes into the specifics on what would be necessary from the configuration standpoint.

You'd need something like the following and supply these properties while bootstrapping the SCDF-server.

```
maven.remote-repositories.nexus.url = "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/...."
maven.remote-repositories.nexus.auth.username = "USER"
maven.remote-repositories.nexus.auth.password = "****"
```

*(where: `nexus` is just a random string; you can call it `repo1` or anything - it doesn't matter - it is just a simple indicator from the user point-of-view)*